# Powershell script doesn't pull certain fields from active directory?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I’m trying to write a PowerShell script to pull users information out of Active Directory and export it to a csv file. I have one partly working but for some reasons some fields in the tables come back blank even though there is data to be extracted? Anyone know why this happening ?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | select domainname, domaincanonicalname, 
samaccountname, displayname, dnid, isdeleted, distinguishedname, cn, 
whencreated, whenchanged, lastlogontimestamp, accountexpires, department, 
pwdlastsetdate, accountdisable, passwd_notreqd, passwd_cant_change, 
dont_expire_password, password_expired | Format-Table -Auto
```

Here are the fields that come out blank;

```
domainname = {}       domaincanonicalnam = {} dnid = {} isselected =
```

Everything else has data in the tables.

Comment: You need to provide more info, tell us what fields aren’t working, what you’ve tried and what happens differently when you make changes. This isn’t a very well written question and you’re being lazy.

Comment: Do a     `get-aduser testuser -properties *` (where testuser is any user in your domain) to find out all properties that are available to you. E.G. You will find     `domainconanicalname` should just be      `conanicalname`,        `whencreated` should just be     `created` etc. Once you are aware of the available properties you will find the command you are running is correct but some the attributes you are interrogating are non existent

Comment: You'll find that, in general, exploring an object using [`Get-Member`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member) provides quite a bit of useful information. Try piping the output of [`Get-ADUser`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx) (as suggested by @itchydon) to `Get-Member`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following - a couple of the properties are missing as I have no idea what you are referring to e.g. "dnid"

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | select canonicalname, 
samaccountname, displayname,  isdeleted, distinguishedname, cn, 
created, Modified, lastlogontimestamp, accountexpires, department, 
PasswordLastSet, Enabled, PasswordNotRequired,  
PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordExpired | Format-Table
```